# Magento - translated product doesn't show

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I made a book store in magento I translted the website into arabic its look fine and I translated a product but it doesn't display yet http://www.gw-egy.com/nct1/index.php/book-categories/social-sciences.html

Answer (score 0):

Do following check:

1. Make sure product is associated with category
2. Make sure product is associated with website
3. Make sure product is active
4. If you have product stock manage, make sure product is in stock

And:

1. Run re-indexing
2. Flush cache, refresh it